# Incompatible java.lang.Float and cannot be instantiated use MultiValueMap

Tags: java, spring

I'm a new to Java and Spring. When I want to use the MultiValueMap in Spring it report is  MultiValueMap is abstract and cannot be instantiated,My code is this:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.util.MutliValueMap;
MultiValueMap<String, List<Float>> dataMap = new MultiValueMap< String, List<Float>>();
```

and I change the sentence to

```
 MultiValueMap<String, List<Float>> dataMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, List<Float>>();
```

It report incompatible java.util.List<java.lang.Float> cannot transfer to java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Float>>. I'm using the jdku172 and `Spring MVC library of version 5.2.2 RELEASE Spring library of version 5.2.2RELEASE`

Comment: Without checking the type definition of `LinkedMultiValueMap`: have you tried to instantiate as `new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Float>()`?

Comment: `MultiValueMap<String, Float> dataMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Float>();` is ok, but I want to connect each key to several float number

Comment: That's exactly what the `MultiValueMap` does. If you declare `MultiValueMap<String, List<Float>>`, then you create a map which can hold multiple float **lists** per key (i.e. list of list).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to associate multiple floato values with a single key, you have to declare the type `MultiValueMap<String, Float>`.

The type `MultiValueMap` [is defined as](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html):

```
public interface MultiValueMap<K,V> extends Map<K,List<V>>
```

To instantiate:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Float> dataMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
```

then

```
dataMap.add("key1", 1.0f);
dataMap.add("key1", 1.1f);
dataMap.add("key1", 1.2f);
dataMap.add("key2", 2.0f);
dataMap.getFirst("key1"); // 1.0f
dataMap.get("key1"); // List.of("1.0f", "1.1f", "1.2f")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to fix your package imports. Here is a an example usage of `MultiValueMap`.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

public class MultiValueMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiValueMap<String, Float> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("Canon", 500.00f);
        map.add("Canon", 501.00f);
        map.add("Canon", 502.00f);

        map.add("Nikon", 550.00f);
        map.add("Nikon", 551.00f);
        map.add("Nikon", 552.00f);

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Float>> e : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I want add several float number to the Value, Is there a method?

Comment: When I  add a float type variable to it show ` float can not transfer to  java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Float>>`

Comment: is map.add  Value can be a  Float  variable?

Comment: It is like we put a  one dimension variable to  two  dimension variable

Comment: Of course you can do it, If you want to add several values you can do it like map.addAll("Sony",  Arrays.asList(550.00f, 551.00f, 552.00f)); or  map.addAll("Panasonic",  Stream.of(550.00f, 551.00f, 552.00f).collect(Collectors.toList())); or  map.addAll("Panasonic",  List.of(550.00f, 551.00f, 552.00f); or map.addAll("Pentax", new ArrayList() {{
            add(550.00f);
            add(551.00f);
            add(552.00f);
        }});

Comment: I want to add a  float variable to the `put` 's value, How do I add map.add(keyid, Value) and keyid  and Value is a float of variable

Comment: Why can't you add float variable?  Float value1 = new Float("120.75f");
        map.add("Canon", value1);

        float value2 = 100.00f;
        map.add("Canon", value2);

Comment: I read a table to the variable in a read text loop.  so when read a line is  `map.add(key,Value)`, and it is  report ` Float cannot transfer to java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Float>>.`

Comment: You've to change your map declaration: MultiValueMap<String, Float> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

Comment: I change the declaration exactly as your write

Comment: and It is report at the line `map.add(key, Value)` ,not the declaration line

Comment: How does your package imports look like? Do you've import java.util.*;. If yes, remove it and use packages that I've given in the answer instead. i.e. import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

Answer (score 0):

MultiValueMap<String, List> dataMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, List>();

This is right. Try using IntelliJ Idea and Spring Boot. That will manage the correct jdk dependency and spring utilities. There is nothing wrong with this line.